# Change span value with jQuery on click function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I very new to front end. And I have an issue on my script.
I want to change dynamically the value of HTML span tag on click with jQuery. I have sidebar menu with products. I have to display only the main category and on click to display the subcategories. The hardest part it "There is a link also on the main category" so I had to add extra button witch will be the trigger for subcategories.

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j('.sidebar-li ul').toggle(); 
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('.sidebar-li .sub-menu').parent('.sidebar-li').wrap('<div class="sidebar-li-plus-icon"></div>'); // Wrap the element in a new class
    $j('.sidebar-li-plus-icon').append('<span class="plus-icon">+</span>'); // add span to the end of the .sidebar-li-plus-icon 
    $j('span.plus-icon').on( 'click' , function(){
        if ( $j(this).is(":visible") ) {
            $j(this).empty().append('<span class="plus-icon">-</span>');
        }
        else if (!$j(this).is(":visible")) {
            $j(this).empty().append('<span class="plus-icon">+</span>');
        }
            $j(this).prev().find('.sub-menu').toggle(100);
    });
});
```

The span is changing on first click but is not returning to previos one after is loaded "-".
Thank you

Comment: You have different class names for the appended span, `plus-icon` and `plus-icons` is this intentional? You might need to use delegated click functions if you are removing and adding the span with the click event on it. i.e. `$('parent-container').on('click','span.plus-icon', function(){});`

Comment: It was my mistake with that `plus-icons` class. I edited the code.

Comment: Instead of creating new `span.plus-icon` why not just change the `text()`?

Comment: Is working also fine with `text()` but my issue is that "else if" statement. I dont know how to get "+" value when the sidebar menu is hidden. `else if (!$j(this).is(":visible")) {
            $j(this).empty().append('<span class="plus-icon">+</span>');
        }` i used "!" for is not visible, but maybe is not the right approach. Bassicaly on the second click on the span element it's need to be back to "+" value